# Scala on Android with SBT

Tags: android, scala, android-studio, sbt

Is there a fast way to get a new sbt 0.13.13, scala 2.12.1 project in Android Studio with Android API 25?

Tried http://scala-android.org/setup/ and http://www.47deg.com/blog/scala-on-android-setting-sbt-configuration and http://srodrigo.me/setting-up-scala-on-android/ and http://scala-on-android.taig.io/proguard/.

Lightbend Activator templates don't build (they use a lot of old versions).